# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. _Val было 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, память, наследование

не понимаю, в чем дело. Уже всё перечитал и перепробовал.

С классом Driver всё в порядке, а при вызове конструктора Autos выдается данная ошибка. Когда классы были раздельными, но реализованы одинаково, то ошибок не возникало.

```
***Autos.h***

#pragma once 

#include <iostream>

class Driver

{

protected:

    std::string* NAME = nullptr;
    int* ID = nullptr;
    bool Status = false;

private:

    static int count;

public:

    Driver() {
        NAME = new std::string("None");
        ID = new int(count);
        count++;
    }

    Driver(std::string name) {
        NAME = new std::string(name);
        ID = new int(count);
        count++;
    }

    
    std::string GetName() {
        return *NAME;
    }
    bool GetStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    void SetStatus(bool IsBusy) {
        this->Status = IsBusy;
    }

    void SetName(std::string a) {
        *this->NAME = a;
    }

    void ShowInfo() {
        std::cout << *NAME << "  " << *ID <<std::endl;
    }
    
    void ChangeName(std::string NewName) {
        delete this->NAME;
        this->NAME = new std::string(NewName);
    }
    
    void ChangeId(int NewId) {
        delete this->ID;
        this->ID = new int(NewId);
    }

    ~Driver() {
        delete NAME;
        delete ID;
    }
    
};

int Driver::count = 0;



class Autos : Driver

{

private:
    
    std::string* DriverName = nullptr;
    static int AutosCount;
    

    введите сюда код

public:

    Autos() {
        
        NAME = new std::string("None");
        ID = new int(AutosCount);
        AutosCount++;
    }

    Autos(std::string Name) {
        NAME = new std::string(Name);
        ID = new int(AutosCount);
        AutosCount++;
    }
    

    Autos(std::string name, Driver &SomeDriver) {
        ID = new int(AutosCount);
        NAME = new std::string(name);
        SomeDriver.SetStatus(true);
        *this->DriverName = SomeDriver.GetName();
        AutosCount++;
    }

    void AttachDriver(Driver &SomeDriver) {
        if (SomeDriver.GetStatus()) {
            throw std::exception("Driver is busy");
        }
        
        *this->DriverName = SomeDriver.GetName();
        SomeDriver.SetStatus(true);
    }
    
    void DeattachDriver() {
        if (this->DriverName == nullptr) {
            throw std::exception("There is no driver attached to this bus.");
        }
        
    }

    std::string GetDriverName() {
        return *this->DriverName;
    }

    void ShowInfo() {
        std::cout << "Bus name: " << *this->NAME << " with id: " << *this->ID << " IsOnline: " << this->Status
            << "\nDriver name: " << this->DriverName << std::endl;
    }
    ~Autos() {
        delete NAME;
        delete ID;
        
    }

};
int Autos::AutosCount = 0;
```

***"main.cpp"***

```
#include "Autos.h"
#include <clocale>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
   
    //Autos Paz("Paz");
    Driver Max("Max");
    Auto
```

s Paz;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте посмотрим, что у вас делается ну, скажем, с полем `NAME`.

Для какового указателя вызывается `delete NAME` и в деструкторе базового класса, и в деструкторе производного.

Одного этого двойного освобождения достаточно...

Вы делаете это же и с `ID`.

Заметим, что вы еще и организовали утечку памяти, выполняя присваивание этим полям в двух конструкторах — базового и производного класса.

P.S. А зачем вам вообще указатели для `NAME` и `ID`?

Comment: Harry, я в силу своей неопытности даже не до конца понимаю как и где использовать указатели, для меня эти две переменные - были динамические переменные. Убрал всё это баловство с указателями и всё идеально работает, благодарю.